# How to make protobufjs generated code smaller

Tags: protobufjs

protobufjs generated code is too large  for front end cases in mobile cases. There is about 300kb while using 3 short proto files.

Bash for generating es6:

```
pbjs -t static-module -w es6 -o proto.js titan.proto --no-convert --no-delimited --no-comments
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a tool based on protobufjs Expansion mechanism：https://github.com/mustime/minipbjs